# Calculate difference between two rows in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I'm trying to calculate the difference between cumulative expense between two rows.

```
Net expenditure for the month = 

var diff= 
'Source data'[Cummulative expense for the month]- 
CALCULATE(
    SUM('Source data'[Cummulative expense for the month]),
    FILTER(
        'Source data',
        'Source data'[index]=EARLIER('Source data'[Numerator])
    )
) 

return 
IF(
    diff=VALUE('Source data'[Cummulative expense for the month]),
    0,
    diff
)
```

Not sure what the mistake is. I'm also attaching a screenshot of the data[image]

Comment: Do your '[Cummulative expense for the month]' is a measure as well?

Comment: yes it is measure

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using power query

```
let
    Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("C:\Users\anumua2\Downloads\im_08nov.xlsx"), null, true),
    Sheet1_Sheet = Source{[Item="Sheet1",Kind="Sheet"]}[Data],
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Sheet1_Sheet, [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",{{"Cumulative Expense for month", type number}}),
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Changed Type", "Index", 1, 1, Int64.Type),
    #"Prev" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "Custom", each #"Added Index"{[Index]-2}[#"Cumulative Expense for month"]),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Prev,{{"Custom", type number}}),
    #"Replaced Errors" = Table.ReplaceErrorValues(#"Changed Type1", {{"Custom", 0}}),
    #"Inserted Subtraction" = Table.AddColumn(#"Replaced Errors", "Subtraction", each [Cumulative Expense for month] - [Custom], type number),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Inserted Subtraction",{{"Custom", "Prev row"}, {"Subtraction", "Net Expenditure for month"}})
in
    #"Renamed Columns"
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I want to get the value using measures. Is it possible in getting the value through measures/dax

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try something as below-

```
Net expenditure for the month = 

var current_row_index = min('Source data'[index])
var current_row_cummulative_expense = min('Source data'[Cummulative expense for the month])

var diff= 
current_row_cummulative_expense - 
CALCULATE(
    SUM('Source data'[Cummulative expense for the month]),
    FILTER(
        ALL('Source data'),
        'Source data'[index] = current_row_index - 1
    )
) 

return 
IF(
    diff=VALUE(min('Source data'[Cummulative expense for the month])),
    0,
    diff
)
```

Comment: Hi thanks for replying. - All values are coming as 0. Any solutions for this?

Comment: Create your [Cummulative expense for the month] as a column. This should solve the issue.

Comment: How can you convert the measure as a column?

Comment: Share your measure code.

Comment: Cummulative expense for the month = 'Source data'[Expense for the month]*(1-'Source data'[attribution rate])